# At which level does a Glamour bard cast the Command spell when they activate Mantle of Majesty?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, bard

At level 6, [Glamour bards](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/bard#CollegeofGlamour) gain the Mantle of Majesty feature (XGtE, p. 14):

> At 6th level, you gain the ability to cloak yourself in a fey magic that makes others want to serve you. As a bonus action, you cast *command*, without expending a spell slot, and you take on an appearance of unearthly beauty for 1 minute or until your concentration ends (as if you were concentrating on a spell). During this time, you can cast *command* as a bonus action on each of your turns, without expending a spell slot.

However it doesn't really mention at what level you cast *command* at. Do you use it as a level 1 spell, or at the highest spell slot you can cast at your level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As ordi's answer pointed out, the Sage Advice Compendium says a spell you can cast without a slot is cast at its lowest level, in this case 1st level.

The Sage Advice Compendium goes on to say that if the special ability allowing you to cast the spell without a spell slot allowed you to upcast it, it would say so.

From the Sage Advice Compendium (v2.3):

> **What level is a spell if you cast it without a spell slot?**
>
> Such a spell is cast at its lowest possible level, which is the level
>   that appears near the top of its description. Unless you have a
>   special ability that says otherwise, the only way to increase the
>   level of a spell is to expend a higher-level spell slot when you cast
>   it. (p 13)

In addition, The Player's Handbook supports this position.  Under Casting a Spell at a Higher Level it says:

> When a spellcaster casts a spell using a slot that is of a higher level than the spell, the spell assumes the higher level for that casting.

Since the bard can't use a spell slot to cast Command, they can't upcast it.

Answer (score 2):

Special abilities that let you cast spells without using spell slots are always cast at the lowest level unless it specify otherwise according to the [Sage Advice Compendium](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/sage-advice-compendium).

Also, monsters use the same rule for [*Innate Spellcasting*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Monsters#toc_28).